# Oracle PreparedStatement - NullPointerException for some developers, but not all

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, prepared-statement

### Project Overview

I have a project with the following attributes:

- **Database:** Oracle 12c

  - **1 table:** MY_TABLE
  - **2 columns:**

    - **ID:** PK, VARCHAR2, 32-byte size limit, Default value = SYS_GUID()
    - **MY_OBJ:** Stores a JSON object for future use
- **Application Framework/Platform**: Spring, Java 8u77

  ---

### The Problem

I am attempting to run the following prepared statement which should output the newly generated key/ID for the inserted object. Unfortunately, I am continually getting a NullPointerException related to the statement.

The curious part of this is that 75% of our team is encountering the same problem, whereas the other **25% of our team has the code working just fine**.

---

### The Question(s)

Why would the following code be working properly on one machine, but returning an error on other machines?

How do I make this work on all machines?

---

### Code

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
    KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    jdbcOracle.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() { //Line 60: This line cited as containing NullPointerException error.

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_OBJ) VALUES (?)", new String[] {"ID"});
            try {
                ps.setString(1, mapper.writeValueAsString(myObj));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ps;
        }

    }, generatedKeyHolder);

    System.out.println("Generated Key: " + (String)generatedKeyHolder.getKeys().get("ID"));
```

---

### Attempted Solutions

1. We've created alternate tables with sequences instead of defaulting to SYS_GUID().
2. We tried using `System.RETURN_GENERATED_KEY` instead of `new String[] {"ID"}`
3. We made sure the DB permissions were identical on all machines.
4. We confirmed that database drivers were identical on all machines.
5. I can remove the `, new String[] {"ID"}` argument along with the `, generatedKeyHolder` argument to get the preparedStatement to run, but since I'm trying to get the generated key this obviously defeats the purpose.

   ---

### Stack Trace

```
2016-05-04 00:05:43.148 ERROR 3156 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaDataColumnIndexes(AutoKeyInfo.java:423) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaData(AutoKeyInfo.java:396) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleReturnResultSet.getMetaData(OracleReturnResultSet.java:77) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:52) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:911) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:900) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:900) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.mysite.impl.MyImpl.save(MyImpl.java:60)
```

Comment: Anything different about the environment on the machines where it's working vs the non-working machines?

Comment: What is myObj object? How is it created/populated? Is it a possibility that myObj is null which is causing NPE?

Comment: Also a stack trace of the exception will help to find the root cause

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis There shouldn't be anything different (although, you can never really be certain, can you?).

Comment: @VishalKamat `myObj` is a JSON object that is properly formed. This doesn't appear to be the culprit. The stack trace is how I know the error is in the `update` line. I'll include the relevant part as an update to the question.

Comment: Not a solution but a workaround: dump the holder and do a insert followed by a 'select ID from x where' afterwards. I had to do this because I had problems too

Comment: stack trace seems like it might be potentially driver related. You mentioned database drivers were identical across all machines but have you tried 12.1.0.2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

12.1.0.1 has a bug regarding key generation. Use Oracle JDBC driver version 12.1.0.2. 
Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: Can't find 12.1.0.2?